# Powershell - Pause Script while External Program Runs

Tags: powershell

I am have a powershell script that does a few things that all need to be completed sequentially. Currently I am using this code to run a couple external programs (assume I am in the correct directory)

```
.\program1.exe
.\program2.exe
.\program3.exe
```

The problem I am having is that these will all run sequentially, not waiting until the previous one is finished. Is there a way to make them wait until the previous program ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most processes will cause PowerShell to wait until their completion unless they do something funky, like Oracle's installers.

You could try:

`Start-Process -FilePath program1.exe -Wait`

If this doesn't work you might have do something like this:

```
& program1.exe 
while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    if (-not (Get-Process -Name program1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        break
    }
}
"...continue here"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(".\program1.exe", ".\program2.exe", ".\program3.exe") | % { & $_ }
```

Stick all the programs in array. Then run the array through a foreach loop that executes them.